# Do I need WordPress Multisite feature for this structure?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I need some advice regarding web structure.

There are two domains: `www.aaa.com` and `www.bbb.com`

They both should share the same content of blogs with more directories. But when user access blogs, they don't need to redirect into other domain so people can access it with

`www.aaa.com/blog` or `www.bbb.com/blog`

With that structure, do I need to use WordPress multisite?

Comment: Is the content exactly the same? Or different? Is the look / feel of the site the same? Or different?

Comment: the domain and the content also the look and feel should be different but I can share the same themes though. The only same content is the blog

Answer (score -1):

If the Blogs are the same, you don't need de multisite.
This feature allows multiple virtual sites to share a single WordPress installation, but if are the same site, you don't need the multisite.

Comment: If the blog are the same I need multisite? Is that what you mean?

I just need the blog to be the same content. the rest of it (domain, content, page, etc should be different)

Comment: So you do not need Multisite. The porpouse of multisite are for multilples sites in the same instalation of wordpress. If they have different, or something different, you will have to use Multisite.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  How does a single WP install answer to two domains, and deliver different content (except the blog, which is the same), and deliver different themes (look / feel)?

Comment: @SergioLopes Well you mean with the same blog post can serve 2 domain?

www.abc.com/blog and www.abcd.com/blog both has same blog? If I use different wordpress installation there would be 2 separate blog post with the same content isn't?

Comment: No my friend, you use this when you have to blogs, but wan't to use one instalation of wordpress.